# Why are all my documents getting deleted when it only should execute and delete only one specific document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I am entering this screen in React Native, all my documents are getting deleted. How can I get the code to delete the document with an doc.id of `key` in `deleteTodo()`. I thought deleteTodo would only execute when `TouchableOpacity` got pressed, but it's getting executed when I am entering the screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
        firebase
         .firestore()
         .collection('users')
         .doc(uid)
         .collection('tasks')
         .get()
         .then((snapshot) => {
       
           const docList = []
       
           snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
             docList.push({
                 key: doc.id,
                 task: doc.data().task,
                 completed: doc.data().completed,
             });
           })
           setList(docList);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error)
         })
       }, [])

       function deleteTodo(key) {
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('tasks').doc(key).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Successfully deleted document!")
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
   }

       swipeRight = (key) => {
           return(
            <View style={styles.rightAction}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteTodo(key)}>
                    <Icon name="trash" size={28} color={"red"} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
           )
       }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Here is your tasks for today</Text>
                    <View style={styles.taskList}>
                        <FlatList style={{width: '100%'}}
                            data={list}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                            renderItem={({item}) => {
                                return(
                                    <Swipeable renderRightActions={() => swipeRight(item.key)}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.task} onPress={() => console.log("This button got pressed")}>
                                            <Text style={{margin: 15, textDecorationLine: item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{item.task}</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </Swipeable>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </View>
                <View style={styles.taskcreation}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputBox}
                        value={task}
                        onChangeText={(task) => setTask(task)}
                        placeholder='What do you want to do?'
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleTaskCreation}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Create task</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are inside flatlist and using item in your render, change the 'key' to 'item' like below:

```
 const deleteTodo = (item) => {
  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection('users')  
   .doc(uid)
   .collection('tasks')
   .doc(item.key)
   .delete()
   .then(() => {
      console.log("Successfully deleted document!")
    })
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
 }


 const swipeRight = (item) => {
     return (
       <RectButton onPress={() => deleteTodo(item)}>
          <Icon name="trash" size={28} color={"red"} />
       </RectButton>
     );
 };
```

for the swipable

```
  <Swipeable renderRightActions={() => swipeRight(item)}>
    <Text style={{margin: 15, 
      textDecorationLine: item.completed ? 'line- 
      through' : 'none'}}>
         {item.task}
    </Text>
  </Swipeable>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. All the documents inside the 'tasks'-collection get deleted.

Comment: if you console log item.key are you geting the document id?

Comment: okay, so when I run console.log(item.key) I get the document ID printed out, but the id is printed out 4 times.

Comment: was the console log inside the deleteTodo method? .doc(item.key)

Comment: Yes the console.log was right under var uid inside deleteTodo

Comment: It seems like deleteTodo is somehow running before I've pressed the TouchableOpacity, but deleteTodo also runs when I press the TouchableOpacity.

Comment: why are you using var? you are using hooks with the latest RN ver? change them to const, some of your code you are using arrow function, maybe clean them up a little make it consistent.

Comment: because it will fire once you press your touchableopacity because it was on the onpress

Comment: I saw wrong, I am using const uid = ...., but I tested out with console.log now, and found out that the documents are getting deleted when the Swipeable is getting rendered, as well as when I am swiping. So, it seems like deleteTodo is running when the Swipeable is rendered and when I am swiping, but does not run when I press the TouchableOpacity in the return in swipeRight.

Comment: but if you put the deleteTodo directly on the <Swipeable renderRightActions={() => deleteTodo(item)}> this will do as well

Comment: Do you have anything more I can try. I don't know how to fix this so deleteTodo won't run when I open the screen.

Comment: which Swipeable package are you using?

Comment: react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable

Comment: I change the above code a little, check if it will work based on https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/swipeable/